# Can't run sudo anymore

Tags: sudo

I was messing around with my sudo file (bad idea), but was trying to get service to start without the use of a passwrd, now i am getting an error:

```
/etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 34 <<< sudo: parse error sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quiting....
```

how can i fix this? i can login with another account, but can't access sudo either...

Comment: Unless you give more details of what this **line 34** (or some previous lines are), how do you xpect someone to help you to fix the error? You can also have a look at `info visudo`